# List all N-digit numbers, with [string] digits

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need a complicated function that given custom digits, and the number of digits, can count out those digits, and spit them out into an array.

For example:

```
function("012", 2, &array_of_string[]);
```

The function should put to the array:

```
{"00", "01", "02", "10", "11", "12", "20", "21", "22"}.
```

You might notice that this array has padding in the front, instead of saying "1", it would output "01". This is required because another function using this array would require the whitespace. The padding can be generated by:

```
function(string Digits, int DigitNum, &array_of_string[]){
//mystery

array_of_string[current_cell] = string(DigitNum - number.length(), Digits[0]) + number;

//mystery
}
```

So the function I would like just needs to generate strings up to certain number of digits with certain base, made out of certain characters.

This is what I wish to accomplish:

```
function("*&$", 4, &array_of_strings[]);
```

would output to array_of_strings[]:

```
{"****","***&","***$","**&*","**&&","**$*","**$&","**$$","*&**","*&*&"... and so forth
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: You could clean up all these variable names in your code fragments and make clear were you failed to implement a permutation of `char` vector members.

Comment: Please show your attempt. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: "I need a complicated function[...]" Why not a simple function? ^^

Comment: :D sorry about that.

Comment: @suspectus Just wrote it for him.

Comment: @EricPetersen Please don't replace the question with a solution. This is already indicated by you accepting the answer. You should leave the question, as anybody else combing here would lose the context otherwise.

Comment: In general, careful with edits modifying the questions substantially, this might invalidate comments and answers given so far.

Comment: ok. I will only ad UPDATE:'s.

Comment: “super's solution uses vectors, but it would be faster and better if it used dynammicly allocated 1d arrays” — do you know what `vector` is???

Comment: Sorry, according to a freind that they are slower, so I also assumed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auto function(const std::string& str, int amount)
{
    std::vector<std::string> swap;
    std::vector<std::string> arr = { "" };

    while (amount--)
    {
        swap.swap(arr);
        arr.clear();
        for(auto& d : swap)
        {
            for (char ch : str)
            {
                auto s = d;
                s += ch;
                arr.push_back(s);
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Comment: `1111`, `11112`, `111123`, `11121` are the first four entries I got for `function("123", 4);` – looks a bit different to what I assume question author is after, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you. This has really helped in my program, although the program crashed if I try to calculate numbers larger than about ("0123456789", 6).